# JDBC: How to connect to a RAC database from Jdbc with details in properties file?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, properties-file

I am trying to connect to an RAC database through JDBC with the connection string in properties file.

Here is the properties file.

```
datasource-url=jdbc\:oracle\:thin\:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=ON)(FAILOVER=ON)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=171.17.aa.ee)(PORT=21521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=171.17.aa.dd)(PORT=21521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=171.17.aa.cc)(PORT=21521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=171.17.aa.bb)(PORT=21521)))(CONNECT_DATA=SERVICE_NAME=ssss)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))
datasource-username=xxxx
datasource-password=yyyy
driver-class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

I am reading this properties file from java code where I create a connection. Unfortunately, I am getting these two exceptions.

```
SQLException-Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid"
SQLException-NL Exception
```

What is wrong here? Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1: I was using odbc14.jar , So I thought of using some other jar. I used odbc7.jar and these 2 exceptions vanished but got a new exception-- SO Exception was generated.

My jdk version is 1.7

Comment: You don't need to escape a `:` in a properties file. Plus you are missing one after the `jdbc`. Try `jdbc:oracle:thin:@(...`

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I am using jdbc/:oracle, did mistake while pasting it here

Comment: Did you try removing the backslash? I don't think it's necessary

Comment: Tried, same exceptions :/

Comment: Actually i do not have answer yet, because still an exception is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, got it working. Posting the properties for others to refer. I used odbc7.jar .

```
datasource-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=171.17.aa.bb)(PORT=21521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=171.17.aa.cc)(PORT=21521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=171.17.aa.dd)(PORT=21521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=171.17.aa.ee)(PORT=21521)))(LOAD_BALANCE=yes)(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=zzzz)))
datasource-username=xxx
datasource-password=yyy
driver-class=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

i.e changed url and driver class. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you are using Java7 you should not use the outdated `odbc14.jar` (which is intended for Java **1.4**) but `ojdbc7.jar`  instead. Also: your driver versions seems to be for Oracle 10. Are you really such an outdated version?

Comment: I tried to use odbc7.jar but it gave SO exception that I found means java and jdbc versions are compitable. So, tried changing it and it worked. Will try again with odbc7.jar and will post the result.

Comment: Got it working with odbc7.jar too. So only changes were url and driver class

Answer (score 0):

You can use either:

- scan listener DNS name: (scan hostname uses DNS loadbalancing, so you get multiple A records for one hostname)

  url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//scan-hostname:port/servicename
- Another option is to use tnsnames.ora file. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19537440/836215). Then you can let DBAs to maintain this a let them make changes in this file.
- 3rd option is to play with quotes and backslashes, till it starts working. I think this `jdbc\oracle` should be rewritten as `jdbc:oracle` or `jdbc\:oracle`.

Comment: Should I create tnsnames.ora file in my project?