# Connection to Oracle via TNS is not working

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, tnsnames, tns

I have a Spring Boot app that works smoothly when it connects to an Oracle instance in the classic way:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@<server name>:<port num>/<service name>
```

However, when I turn to a connection via tns through a tnsnames.ora stored in my local drive "C:\ORACLE\Client11g\network\admin" something doesn't work and I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
    ... 52 more

10:37:32,201 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 381) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./my_service: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./my_service: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [app/persistence/OracleConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [app/persistence/OracleConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:236)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [app/persistence/OracleConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:186)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:171)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:234)
    ... 8 more
```

The following is my application.properties + application-oracleprod.properties files. Keep in mind that this approach works when I use a SID connection as previously said.

application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=oracleprod

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

application-oracleprod.properties (here the magic should happen due to this property "oracle.net.tns_admin" which sets the "tnsnames.ora" folder plus the link "@MY_SERVICE" which is obviously present in the "tnsnames.ora" file, but I really don't see what Oracle does under the hood):

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

#/tnsnames.ora
oracle.net.tns_admin=C:/ORACLE/Client11g/network/admin

oracle.username=my_user
oracle.password=xyz
oracle.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@MY_SERVICE
```

The Configuration class is clean and straightforward:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="oracle" )
public class OracleConfiguration {

    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private String url;

    /*@Value("${oracle.net.tns_admin}")
    private String tns;*/

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    /*public void setTns(String tns) {
        this.tns = tns;
    }*/

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource(); // we use oracle data source API but it could be mysql
        dataSource.setURL(this.url);
        dataSource.setUser(this.username);
        dataSource.setPassword(this.password);
        dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
        dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        try {
            em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "app.persistence.entity" }); // put the name of entity classes package 

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        //em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties()); // this properties are set by "application-oracle.properties" file

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

To summarize, I have followed the approach suggested in the Oracle documentation in combination with Spring Boot configuration files/class with no luck.

I have also tried different path formats:

```
C:/ORACLE/Client11g/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
C:\ORACLE\Client11g\network\admin
C:\\ORACLE\\Client11g\\network\\admin
```

I think I'm doing well because with a SID connection everything is perfect but probably something hidden is missing.

**UPDATE**

It turned out the db url is not correct, at least for a TNS connection. The thing is we have something like multiple hosts and not only a single one:

```
    MY_SERVICE =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (LOAD_BALANCE = off)
    (FAILOVER = on)
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 5)
      (TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 3)
      (RETRY_COUNT = 3)
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (LOAD_BALANCE = on)
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <ip_1> )(PORT = 1621))
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <ip_2> )(PORT = 1621))
      )
      (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVICE_NAME = <my_service_name>)
      )
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 5)
      (TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 3)
      (RETRY_COUNT = 3)
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (LOAD_BALANCE = on)
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <ip_3> )(PORT = 1621))
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <ip_4> )(PORT = 1621))
      )
      (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVICE_NAME = <my_service_name> )
      )
    )
  )
```

And I got:

```
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Errore di I/O: Unknown host specified 
    Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unknown host specified "
```

Again, I'm a little bit confused how to tell Spring how to read this TNS configuration.

Any idea?

Comment: You have putted loads of code here, It will be difficult for anybody to 1st understand your question and then answer it. Please be specific and precise in asking question.Please have a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting a question

Comment: You are setting spring.jpa.database-platform to the Oracle-dialect, Have you tried to set set the hibernate-property, too?(as requested in the exception)

Comment: So you are setting properties in `application.properties` used for auto configuration. Next create your own configuration, disabling auto configuration, and find it strange that the properties aren't applied. In short no properties from your `application.properties` will be used/applied. And the question arise why do you even have this configuration class? You don't really need it as Spring Boot can configure all that for you out-of-the-box.

Comment: @GeekyNinja Omitting that code wouldn't show a complete and verifiable example

Comment: @Turo I don't understand to which property you are referring to. Could you explain better?

Comment: @M.Deinum That class is mandatory or my EntityManager won't be initialized in my app. Removing the class throws a datasource instance exception.

Comment: Not if you configure it correctly... Even if it would fail you would only need to configure a `DataSource` not everything else.

Comment: As stated in the HibernateException: you could set  'hibernate.dialect'  to org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect, too. It probably won't fix the problem, but maybe you get another exception which is closer to the problem.

Comment: That is the actual issue, but that comes from the fact that using that configuration class disables auto-configuration and basically rendering the `spring.datasource` and `spring.jpa` properties in `application.properties` useless as those will get ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your class you are basically disabling auto-configuration and thus rendering, a large part, of your `application.properties` useless.

There is nothing in your `OracleConfiguration` that isn't (or can be) automatically configured for you.

**Note:** I'm assuming 2 things, first you are using [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) as the connection pool and second you are using Spring Boot 1.4.x.

So for starters remove the `OracleConfiguration` class and fix the `application.properties` accordingly.

```
# DataSource
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource

#JPA   
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

#Hibernate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

You don't need the `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` as that will be derived from the URL.

In your `application-oracle.properties` (or whatever profile name you use) set the following

```
# DataSource
spring.datasource.username=my_user
spring.datasource.password=xyz
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@MY_SERVICE

spring.datasource.hikari.dataSourceClassName=oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.dataSourceProperties.implicitCachingEnabled=true
spring.datasource.hikari.dataSourceProperties.fastConnectionFailoverEnabled=true

#JPA   
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

This configures the oracle specific JDBC properties.

The `spring.datasource.hikari.dataSourceProperties` are needed to set the additional properties in the `OracleDataSource`.

This should allow Spring Boot to automatically create the `DataSource` and appropriate `EntityManagerFactory` without you needing to create a custom configuration class at all.

### Update (Config without Hikari and plain `OracleDataSource`)

If you want to use the plain `OracleDataSource` instead of a connection pool you could remove the `spring.datasource.type` from the default `application.properties` and add the following to the `application-oracle.properties`.

```
# DataSource
spring.datasource.type=oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
spring.datasource.username=my_user
spring.datasource.password=xyz
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@MY_SERVICE
```

Which results in more or less the same as you manually configured.

### Update #2

As you want to use TNS you also need to set a system property named `oracle.net.tns_admin`. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536162/how-to-connect-jdbc-to-tns-oracle)).

So in your application initializer (if not set on your app server) you need to set it manually.

```
private static void determineAndSetTnsHome() {
    String tnsAdmin = System.getenv("TNS_ADMIN");
    if (tnsAdmin == null) {
        String oracleHome = System.getenv("ORACLE_HOME");
        if (oracleHome == null) {
            return; //failed to find any useful env variables            
        }
        tnsAdmin = oracleHome + File.separatorChar + "network" + File.separatorChar + "admin";
    }
    System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", tnsAdmin);
}
```

Call this method from your `main` and `onStartup` or `configure` method. This assumes you have the `ORACLE_HOME` or `TNS_ADMIN` variable set in your environment.

Comment: Thank you. It actually works with the SID connection. However I still face problems with TNS connection. At this point I wonder the purpose of a configuration class. Is it to configure manually the datasource without relying on .properties files (specifying connection criteria in the code)?

Comment: You don't need a configuration class. (And your question in the comment is for another question). I highly doubt that, with this configuration files, you get the same exception (if you have removed the configuration class that is).

Comment: Yes, the exception is different. I have updated the main question. The problem with the TNS connection persists, but of course I misunderstood something with the datasource configuration.

Comment: You saved my day. I wonder why adding the property "oracle.net.tns_admin" in .properties file doesn't do the trick. It would be definitely cleaner and efficient. I will further investigate a way to do that without putting extra code in my spring boot "Application.java". The reason is I would like to have two oracle configurations in order to switch from one to another based on development/production environments.

Comment: Just use profiles for that and add 2 property files for both `application-[profile].properties`. Simply adding it to the properties file doesn't work because apparently the Oracle driver reads that property from the system environment. The Oracle driver doesn't now (nor should it) about spring. You could create a small configuration which adds the specific property as System property (instead of what you have now).

Comment: After all, leaving that configuration in the code is not a big deal. When I choose the development environment, it just sets the system variable but it doesn't use it. Again, thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, for me only worked:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=TODO)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=TODO)))
```

instead of `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@MY_SERVICE.`

Also I'm calling the method determineAndSetTnsHome() suggested by the user M. Deinum in the accepted answer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EvaApplication.class, args);
        determineAndSetTnsHome();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lame method actually, 
but it worked perfectly

Put this in your Main class.

```
    System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin",
            "<Path of tnsnames.ora>");
```

Use this in your properties file

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@ORCLPDB

I am still digging more. Will give update here