# Spring Boot Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, datasource, application.properties

I'm building an application using spring boot and need to connect to Oracle DB via service, not sid.

These are datasource settings:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname.companyname.corp:1500/servicename.companyname.com
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=SCHEMA_NAME
```

I've already explored two other responses regarding tns connection:
[Connection to Oracle via TNS is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424589/connection-to-oracle-via-tns-is-not-working)
and 
[How to connect JDBC to tns oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536162/how-to-connect-jdbc-to-tns-oracle)

But I'm hitting a different error:

> org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not
>   get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not
>   get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException    at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:339)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:366)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:139)
>   [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:105)
>   [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$47d988e9.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$4()
>   [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$47d988e9$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$27b4f4ca.invoke()
>   [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>   [spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
>   [spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$47d988e9.jpaVendorAdapter()
>   [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_152]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_152]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_152]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_152]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
>   [spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
>   [spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   [spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]     at
>   com.swift.cpms.CpmsWebApp.main(CpmsWebApp.java:18) [classes/:na]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException:
>   Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:326)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  ... 61 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: null    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:323)
>   ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
>   ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735)
>   ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667)
>   ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482)
>   ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.(ConnectionPool.java:154)
>   ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
>   ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
>   ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131)
>   ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  ... 62 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException: null    at
>   java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]   at
>   java.nio.ByteBuffer.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]   at
>   oracle.net.ns.NIOAcceptPacket.readPayloadBuffer(NIOAcceptPacket.java:167)
>   ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]     at
>   oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readNIOPacket(NIOPacket.java:282)
>   ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]     at
>   oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:118)
>   ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]     at
>   oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:317)
>   ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1438)
>   ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518)
>   ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688)
>   ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
>   ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
>   ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310)
>   ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]  ... 72 common frames omitted

If I switch to debug mode I get a little more details and exception happens right after:

> 2018-03-01 15:34:21.435 DEBUG 44920 --- [           main]
>   o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection
>   from DataSource 2018-03-01 15:34:21.446 DEBUG 44920 --- [
>   main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection    : Instantiating driver
>   using class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
>   [url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//exa22-scan8.swift.corp:1500/cpmsdev_usr.swift.com]
>   2018-03-01 15:34:21.447 DEBUG 44920 --- [           main]
>   o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil     : Attempting to load
>   class[oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] from
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@659e0bfd

I'm using the same URL, service_name, and credentials to connect to DB in sqldeveloper and can confirm that that part is correct. I also tried options suggested in above links setting up

```
System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", "C:/ora12/client_1/network/admin");
```

and setting url @service_name with the same result

I'm completely lost on what can be the reason for it - incorrect syntax or anything else? 
Does anyone else have any suggestion what can cause it and what can be a possible solution?

pom.xml dependecnies

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>       
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
  <version>12.2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Appreciate any suggestions or help on it!

Comment: Please add the whole error message. In your first log line there is a nested SQLException with the actual root cause. Your log says `nested exception is java.sql.SQLException` but you didn't show it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out the issue was caused by the size of the etc/issue file on the db server. Switching to older ojdbc6 driver is an optional soution or reducing the size of the etc/issue on linux box is the other one.

Comment: I'm having this problem with mysql - but can't see how /etc/issue relates to a database problem? Although I can't actually look at it because it's an Amazon RDS...

Comment: It's a bug, which, in my case, driver version had. When it was reading this file it hit some internal error because of the file content size.

Answer (score 0):

Change url to:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname.companyname.corp)(PORT=1500))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=servicename.companyname.com)))
```

Comment: I tried this option too, unfortunatly, with the same result.

Comment: Please provide a full stacktrace and try set:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

Comment: Did you tried it again with my suggestion, but replacing only the host name and service name ?