# How to configure tnsnames.ora file with Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot

I am aware how to configure db connection using jdbc string

```
#Basic Spring Boot Config for Oracle
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:sid
    username: user
    password: pwd
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    continueOnError: true
```

How do i do the same if i should be using `tnsnames.ora` file ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a TNS alias in the connection string and as long as you set TNS_ADMIN to the place where tnsnames.ora file is present, you are set.

Note that passing TNS_ADMIN as part of the URL requires [18.3 JDBC drivers](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/jdbc-ucp-183-5013470.html).

**jdbc:oracle:thin:@wallet_dbname?TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin**

## tnsnames.ora

testdb = (description= (address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1521)(host=myorclhost))(connect_data=(service_name=myorclservice)))

Answer (score 0):

First, determine which directory your TNSNAMES.ora file lives in. It is usually stored at `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin`, but this may vary depending on how your client was installed.

Once you have the location of your TNSNAMES.ora file, you should set a property called `oracle.net.tns_admin` to point to that directory. Once the property is set, you specify the database you are trying to connect to.

Here are a couple of great examples that cover this method:

[Connection to Oracle via TNS is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424589/connection-to-oracle-via-tns-is-not-working)

[How to connect JDBC to tns oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536162/how-to-connect-jdbc-to-tns-oracle)