# Java: Using Relative Directory Path on Windows

Tags: java, environment-variables, relative-path

Is there any way to get relative path in Java for Windows, something like the Environment Variables- `%systemdrive%`, `%appdata%` or `%temp%`?

Like in C using `windows.h` we can do this-

```
char* appdataFolderPath = getenv("APPDATA");
```

---

**Edit:** I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18128616/4684058) solution. But it does not work!

Comment: You appear to be asking two things - how do you get an environment variable; and how do you get a relative path.

Comment: @AndyTurner I only want to store some data in the `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming` directory. I needed to know- **how**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method `System.getenv`. Here is how you do it:

```
final String value = System.getenv("APPDATA");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below code to get all the environment variables.. see the logic and implement it as needed.

```
  public static void main (String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
            System.out.format("%s=%s%n",
                              envName,
                              env.get(envName));
        }
    }
```